# eCommerce homepage for multiple customer types: How?

Tags: e-commerce

Company has mainly been dealing with businesses and large scale customers but now wants to expand its eCommerce side.

In general, what are the best practices to appeal to both segments? How do we implement an e-shop without looking cheap for larger customers who came to the site looking for contact information and services offered.

We could obviously just make a "Shop" menu item but management wants a "strong sense of eCommerce" on their home page.

Any advice? Example sites would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: Think this is more of a visual design related. A website could look "cheap" yet still have a great user experience and vice versa.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely diversify e-commerce section for these two segments. There is two approaches to it, depending on the context.

1. Diversified pages in the overall site structure: "Solutions for Businesses" and "Solutions for the Clients". Each page has to suggest a sensible overview of the product advantages and a CTA or multiple CTAs throughout the content sections. This is good for offers that are different in quality, i.e., to Businesses you offer conference systems and to Clients phone apps.

[image]

2. A common "pricing plans" page with the grid of offered points. Good for cases when the diversification is quantitative — i.e. when you sell a package of 5 accounts to Businesses and a 1 account package to individual Clients.

[image]

If you have to put it literally on the Home page, as in Index, then it's possible to do a modular section that will either transfer users to the respective solution page or display shortened versions of the pricing plans and will lead to the pricing plans page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a larger research, there are many companies that are doing well on both B2B and B2C market and the difference is not just an eshop. 
Pick companies similar to yours (size, business...) and look for interesting techniques and their implementation. Also case studies published by digital agencies working on such projects might help a lot.